# javaScript minesweeper empty fields reveal

Tags: javascript, recursion, minesweeper

I am trying to create a minesweeper game using html css and js. I created the board, the fields(div elements), planted the bombs, every field "knows" his position (x,y) (the x and y coordinates are saved as data attributes of the div), "knows" if he is a bomb and the number of bombs nearby. I managed to create onclick event to reveal if the tile is a bomb or to show the number of bombs nearby. Now my problem is that if i click on a tile which has no bombs nearby (empty tile) i want to reveal all empty tiles which are in the surrounding.
So the next function is called if i click on an empty field:

```
function zero(x, y) {
    for (var i = x - 1; i <= x + 1; i++) {
        for (var j = y - 1; j <= y + 1; j++) {
            $('.tile[row-d=' + i + '][col-d=' + j + ']').text($('.tile[row-d=' + i + '][col-d=' + j + ']').attr('bomb_number')); // set the field text = bomb -number nearby
        }
    }
}
```

With this i reveal all the surrounding fields near the clicked empty field, so i reveal just 9 fields. I want to reveal all empty fields nearby not just 9. I tried to use recursive function but the page crashed.
So anybody can help me with a recursive function which could solve this. Thank you. (As you can see i am also using jQuery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic rule is:

- If you find a neighboring field that is next to a bomb, stop searching
- If a neighboring field has no bomb, keep expanding to the new field's neighbors

In code:

```
function zero(x, y) {
    for (var i = x - 1; i <= x + 1; i++) {
        for (var j = y - 1; j <= y + 1; j++) {
            var neighbor = $('.tile[row-d=' + i + '][col-d=' + j + ']');
            var bombNr = neighbor.attr('bomb_number');

            neighbor.text(bombNr);

            if (bombNr === "0") zero(i, j);
        }
    }
}
```

*Edit: a quick & dirty example of the recursion pattern*:

```js
// The recursive function
const handleInput = i => {
  if (tapped.has(i)) return;
  
  // Count the bombs in neighboring tiles
  const bombs = neighbors(i)
    .map(j => board[j])
    .filter(v => v === x)
    .length;

  // Store the count so we can render it
  tapped.set(i, bombs);
  
  // If there are no bombs, handle all the neighbors'
  // as well.
  if (bombs === 0) {
    neighbors(i).forEach(handleInput);
  }
};

// Game state
const x = "x";
const board = [
  x, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  x, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  x, x, x, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, x, 0, 0
];

const tapped = new Map();

// Quick & dirty render method to visualize what happens
const render = board => {
  const el = document.querySelector(".board")
  
  el.innerHTML =
    board
      .map((v, i) => tapped.has(i) ? tapped.get(i) : v)
      .map(txt => `<div>${txt}</div>`)
      .join("");
    
  Array.from(el.children).forEach((c, i) => {
    c.addEventListener("click", () => {
      
      if (board[i] === x) return console.log("Boom!");
      
      handleInput(i);
      
      render(board);
      
    });
    
    c.classList.toggle("tapped", tapped.has(i));
  });
}

const row = i => i / 5 << 0;
const col = i => i % 5;
const neighbors = i => {
  const top =    [ -6, -5, -4 ];
  const right =  [ -4,  1,  6 ];
  const bottom = [  4,  5,  6 ];
  const left =   [ -6, -1,  4 ];
  
  const ds = new Set([...top, ...right, ...bottom, ...left]);
  const remove = d => ds.delete(d);
  
  if (row(i) === 0) top.forEach(remove);
  if (row(i) === 4) bottom.forEach(remove);
  if (col(i) === 0) left.forEach(remove);
  if (col(i) === 4) right.forEach(remove);

  return [...ds].map(d => d + i);
};

render(board);
```

```css
.board {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
}

.board > div {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.board > div.tapped {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="board"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i tried something like this and it didn't work, but i tried your code just to be sure, and i get same result which is no output is displayed, the page freezes, any other button which is on the page is not working, i can't refresh the page, and an error is thrown after like 30 sec: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded. So any good advice?

Comment: I quickly threw together a demo app to show how the `bombs === 0` check can trigger the recursive pattern on the neighboring tiles. It's far from perfect (shared state, bad renders, etc.), but might help you get the point...

Comment: Thanks for your help. It is kind a hard to understand for me (after all i am just a beginner in js). I managed to find the solution. I find a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34459086/minesweeper-reveal-nearby-tiles-function , modified it a little bit and it's working perfect.

Comment: Recursion can be difficult and to be honest, my example isn't very beginner-friendly... Make sure you use your debugger to step through each step and if you can't figure it out, you can always start out with a loop-based approach :)

Comment: I just tested my own previous version which didn't work, and i managed to fix it. My problem was that i didn't check if the tile was revealed, after i put an if statement to check it, it worked perfect. Again thanks for your effort.